# Exception handling in class library. Is it necessary?

Tags: asp.net, exception, code-reuse

I have a class library project which i am referencing in my asp.net web forms project.

Whenever any exception happens, i want to log it. But, I am not doing any exception handling in any of the class library method. That is i have not used try-cath block in any of the methods in the class library.

Because, any excepyion that gets thrown from class library methods is caught in my presentation layer/business layer(wherever i call the functions of the class library) and proper logging is done here in the web forms project.

Is it correct to do this way.?

Comment: Yes, this is right way of doing it. even if you are catching exception in your library for logging purpose. its better to throw it after logging to the user class

Comment: Usually I create a separate Project in my solution that logs every single Exception with the originating project, thus you accomplish re-usability in all your projects.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. hi wizpert, can you give more details on your point. i am interested to know about it. Or just post a link where i can find more on this... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Its Ok to write that way, but in that case your Class Library will throw exception which system exception message, which might be sometime difficult to interpret and act accordingly.

Instead you can have Try-Catch-Finally block in class library, and Re-throw exception with user defined message to calling method, this will help in tracing issue.

Example :

```
Catch(FileNotFoundException Ex)
{
  throw new ("File Not Found at XYZ Location, Please Check File Exist and retry ...")
}
```

Centralized Exception Logging:

There are multiple ways you can log error messages. One of the good way would be to use Enterprise Library Exception Block to Log error to file, which can be used in debugging issues.

This article can come handy for Enterprise Library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649140.aspx

You can log exception centrally to CSV, XML or even to windows Event Viewer.

Create Separate class / project to perform all exception logging in project.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a reasonable approach to me. Delegating the exception logging to the application keeps your class library abstract meaning it can be reused without having a dependency on the logging library/framework.

Logging should be the responsibility of the application, not the component. There may be some exceptional circumstances where trace-level debugging is required at component level, for those special cases having a log-enabled version of the lib that you could swap in might come in handy. However, I would argue that a properly tested component would reduce the need for that.